# Can I run XAMPP installed on Windows partition

Tags: 12.04, windows, xampp

I have been using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) on Windows 7. Now, I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows. I just want to use my XAMPP from Windows while I'm on Ubuntu.

I know how can I install and get running XAMPP on Ubuntu, but there have been many PHP program files and MySQL databases in my Windows XAMPP. I need to run those from Ubuntu so that I don't need to re-install XAMPP and start from stretch.

Do I need to use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) to get the Windows Apache running on my Ubuntu?
Or any other instruction to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It is close to impossible to run Win XAMPP on Ubuntu out of a Win7 partition, and you would run in all sorts of issues if you would be able to accomplish this.

What you could do though is:

Install Apache on ubuntu with mod_php or whatever you need, and then setup your virtual hosts to point to the Win7 partition.

But be careful you will run in all sorts of issues with document encoding when you switch between system ...

I would not recommend this for webdevelopment ... rather create a git repository of your sites and then you can syncronice your work with a simple

```
git pull
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please expand your answer a little for your two points - virtual hosts and git?

Comment: I don't have much time. Basically you would have two instances of XAMPP, one for Win7 and one for Ubuntu. But you could use git to syncronize your application root directory. Git is a tool that keeps track of file changes and lets you manage or move your files accross systems.